# MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordDeprecationMacros.h file not found

Tags: magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2, magicalrecord-2.1

I down load the  Magical Record master. Drag the MagicalRecord folder to my project. Import CoreData.framework then build. Show the error "MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordDeprecationMacros.h file not found", Please see the images [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you're inside MagicalRecord's `NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalRecord.h` header file. [image] These files are setup to work with your code and generally don't require any changes. I would recommend going over RayWenderlich's [MagicalRecord](http://www.raywenderlich.com/56879/magicalrecord-tutorial-ios) tutorial. It's a step by step guide to working with MagicalRecord in CoreData.

Comment: Yes, I change #import<> to import "xxxx.h".    And thanks for answer my question ^_^